# Django and AddThis Social SignIn

Tags: python, django, registration, django-registration, addthis

I am developing a Django website. I've been using django-registration for user registration so far but I would really like to allow users to login to my site using their Facebook, Twitter, Google, etc accounts.

I am using addthis sharing buttons. I just noticed they introduced a social sign in solution. The idea seems great, you integrate your authentication system with their service once, and your users can login via all of the popular social networking sites.

Has anybody integrated addthis social signin plugin with a django website? How can you use it along side django-registration? Are there any similar, alternative solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Python Social auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) for Facebook, Twitter and Co
and [Django Registration](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration) for a registration and password reset via Email.